# How to get X Y coordinates of element in Selenium WebDriver with node.js

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

```
elem = driver.getElementSize(webdriver.By.xpath("//some_path"));
var width = elem.getSize().getWidth();
```

I am trying to get the dimension of an element in selenium-webdriver and node js. I have tried this code and it gives me below error:

```
TypeError: driver.getElementSize is not a function
```

Is there a function for getting the size of an element?

Answer (score 2):

getRect() method returns the dimensions.

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_WebElement.html